# Mapillary JS: mapillary-js storytelling [RouteComponent] hangs

Tags: javascript, mapillary

I'm trying to use Mapillary JS (rif. http://blog.mapillary.com/update/2016/02/10/mapillary-js.html), to build a storytelling following this sample http://bl.ocks.org/knikel/630c2d6fa37a8a0e082a.

This is my code ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/mapillary-js@1.0.1/dist/mapillary-js.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/mapillary-js@1.0.1/dist/mapillary-js.min.css"/>
  <style>
    body { background-color: silver; }
    .mly-wrapper { margin: 0 auto; }

    .mly-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      background-color: grey;
      width: 640px;
      height: 480px;
    }
    #mly, .mapillary-js {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mly-wrapper"><div class="mly" id="mly-route"></div></div>
<button onclick="play()">Play</button><button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
<script>
var play = undefined;
var stop = undefined;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var mlyRoute = new Mapillary.Viewer('mly-route', 'cjJ1SUtVOEMtdy11b21JM0tyYTZIQTo2ZmVjNTQ3YWQ0OWI2Yjgx', 'yzqmDDZkw9EJ0WHG9NgUHQ',
                                       {cover: true, cache: false, direction: false});
  var route = mlyRoute.getComponent("route");

  route.configure({paths: [
   {sequenceKey: "kwAhQXNeJ16ydpMdRbfAQA", startKey: "yzqmDDZkw9EJ0WHG9NgUHQ", stopKey: "yzqmDDZkw9EJ0WHG9NgUHQ",
     infoKeys: [
       {key: "yzqmDDZkw9EJ0WHG9NgUHQ", description: "a"}
     ]},
   {sequenceKey: "Lm7zCv3niXy9jBDmaKEuzw", startKey: "lQ13qzAfQs5OEGM4H2pZew", stopKey: "lQ13qzAfQs5OEGM4H2pZew",
     infoKeys: [
       {key: "lQ13qzAfQs5OEGM4H2pZew", description: "b"}
     ]},
   {sequenceKey: "gfTD_L8gjAvxjh42pzRJwQ", startKey: "jH8YqGpUo-biE1MpKVjFIw", stopKey: "jH8YqGpUo-biE1MpKVjFIw",
     infoKeys: [
       {key: "jH8YqGpUo-biE1MpKVjFIw", description: "c"}
     ]}
  ], playing: true});
  mlyRoute.activateComponent("route");

  play = function play() {
      mlyRoute.deactivateCover();
      route.play();
  }

  stop = function stop() {
      route.stop()
  }
})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to execute it nothing is happening and no errors are in the web browser console.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to load the page over https, since the mapillary API is now on https.

https://bl.ocks.org/knikel/630c2d6fa37a8a0e082a should work?

Comment: The Mapillary test works for me also in http .... in any case I've tried my sample page in https too but ....no changes ... .:-(

Comment: ... did you tried my sample code?

Comment: Yes, I just tested. Your code works locally for me in Chrome without modifications.

Comment: Uhmmm ... interesting. This would be a great news for me. In my Chrome (Version 51.0.2704.106 m), the "video" hangs, and I can see only the first image .... quite strange. Which Chrome version are you using? Do you simply double-click on the html page or are you put it behind a web server? Do you load the page over http or https? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I put it behind a local webserver, with only the copied code, and loaded it in Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit) so things should be working ...

Comment: I've tried to put the page under another web server and it's working ... I don't know why. Quite strange. But the problem with pages that hang still remain .. .I've another sample that I put here ... https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2iosOWehVIuclJuaTJ2WWw3ZTA. (I've tried to test it under different web server ... :-) ... )  Please, could you try this one too? Thanks a lot!

Comment: ops ... now my original page, that before was working, hangs again!! Now you can try it directly!! http://www.cesaregerbino.com/Mapillary/TestManuale2.html

Comment: Something goes wrong when load the same page more than once?

Comment: Works good for me on Chrome, OSX. Good work!